# Как настроить 301 редирект со страниц всех уровней раздела на корневую .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть корневой раздел каталога сайта "dveri" имеющий подразделы
и целевые страницы у каждого подраздела.

Структура каталога относительно корня сайта выглядит так:

```
site.ru/catalog/dveri/dveri_derevo/derevanaya_dver
site.ru/catalog/dveri/dveri_stal/stalnaya_dver
site.ru/catalog/dveri/dveri_steklo/steclanaya_dver
```

Нужно со всех страниц подразделов раздела "dveri" сделать 301 редирект
на "dveri".

Пробуемые мной конструкции:

```
#Redirect 301 /catalog/dveri/(.*) /catalog/dveri/
#Redirect 301 /catalog/dveri/dveri_stal/(.*) /catalog/dveri/
```

Правила описанные выше пробуемой конструкции

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Опция позволяет использовать символические ссылки на файлы или каталоги, не находящиеся в пределах корня вашего сайта.
Options +FollowSymLinks
# Включаем mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
# Условие, что все существующие файлы не будут обрабатываться регулярным выражением
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Условие на запрет обработки символических ссылок
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# Условие, что все существующие папки не будут обрабатываться регулярным выражением
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
RewriteEngine On # эта команда у вас уже есть скорее всего
RewriteRule ^catalog/dveri/.+$ /catalog/dveri/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: К сожалению не сработало

Comment: Появилась ошибка 404

Comment: во время тестирования ставьте 302 редирект. на какую страницу переправляет?

Comment: Спасибо что вы мне помогаете!
У меня пока возникли вопросы к описанным в файле .htaccess правилам выше того что пытаюсь использовать, видимо они создают проблему для обработки нижних правил.

Comment: Обновил вверху вопрос добавив правила из файла выше

Comment: 302 редирект отрабатывает так-же как и 301

Comment: так поставьте правило сразу после  RewriteEngine On. если вы используете 301, то браузер запоминаем предыдущее (возможно не правильное) значение и чтобы он отреагировал на новое нужно чистить кэш... при 302 он каждый раз смотрит правила и той проблемы нет... когда настроите, потом измените на 301

Comment: Пробовал ставить правило сразу под RewriteEngine On,
чистил кеш, тестировал в новой вкладке. Проверял работоспособность модуля.
Сейчас никакой реакции на правило не наблюдаю, как будто его нет.
Но простой редирект —работает в любом месте.

#Redirect 301/catalog/dveri/.*$ /catalog/dveri/dveri_derevo/

Comment: а если без слеша страница назначения RewriteRule ^catalog/dveri/.*$ /catalog/dveri [L,R=302,NC] ?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению регулярки не хотят работать.